# mkisofs undo "--hide" option

Tags: linux

is it possible to recover any documents that has been placed on a CD using the "--hide" option? I was unable to find any information regarding this on the net. Maybe sb here knows the answer, should be possible since the data is present on the CD, as my hexdump tells me.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which `--hide` option was used when the CD was created:

```
-hide              Hide a file/directory from the ISO9660/Rock Ridge directory
-hide-list         As above, but read file names from a file
-hide-joliet       Hide a file/directory from the Joliet directory
-hide-joliet-list  As above, but read file names from a file
-hide-hfs          Hide a file/directory from the HFS directory
-hide-hfs-list     As above, but read file names from a file
```

If the file was hidden with `--hide-joliet` it will be excluded from the directory tree when mounted as Joliet CD, but will be visible like this:

```
mount -t iso9660 -o nojoliet /dev/cdrom /mount/point
```

with a shortened 8.3 name. Conversely, if the file was hidden only with `--hide` it will be visible mounted as Joliet CD:

```
mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /mount/point
```

If the file was hidden for ISO9660/Rock Ridge **and** Joliet the file will be invisible. From `README.hide` included with mkisofs:

> **The various -hide options actually exclude the relevant directory entry
>   from the directory tree.** Therefore, it is not possible to access a file
>   or directory that has be hidden with the -hide option when the ISO9600/Rock
>   Ridge directory is mounted - because the directory entry does not exist on the
>   CD (but the file data does). You would probably be able to access this file
>   or directory when mounted as a Joliet or HFS CD (depending on other options
>   used). Similarly, a directory entry hidden with the -hide-joliet option
>   will not be accessible when mounted as an Joliet CD. Similarly for -hide-hfs
>   etc.

Comment: Thanks but that is for the "--hidden" option, not the "--hide" option ...

Comment: @Steven, yes, you are right, I confused both options, thanks for pointing it out. I've edited my answer for the `--hide` option.